# ¿Cómo posicionar un botón en android studio?

Tags: android, xml

Tengo un botón dentro de un linear layout, deseo que el boton este fijo en la parte final de la pantalla.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAceptar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="ENVIAR DENUNCIA"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlanco" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto depende del contenedor principal, ¿Estas usando ConstrainLayout? , te recomiendo agregar todo el layout.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas puedes encontrar la forma de hacerlo en : [linear layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout#xml-attributes)

La forma de realizar lo que quieres seria añadir al boton el campo [gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout#attr_android:gravity)
con el valor 50 (bottom) o 800005 (final).

Quedaria de la siguiente forma :

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/bAceptar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="ENVIAR DENUNCIA"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlanco"
        android:gravity=50/>
```

Comment: Gravity 50  no funciono, sigue sin estar al final de mi pantalla el boton :(

Comment: gravity=800005 tampoco?? Si no te funciona asi, No sabria decirte como solucionarlo

Answer (score 0):

Buenas la mejor forma para hacer esto es agregar un ConstraitLayout por fuera del LinearLayout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/la"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAceptar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="ENVIAR DENUNCIA" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Y al LinearLayout le agregas la propiedad: `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`